# Cannot change AAD group settings

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

All options are greyed out. Checking my own role is also greyed out, though I assume that is, because I am the only global administrator.

I also tried to access the classic portal, but can't, as I don't have the necessary subsriptions.

User Settings all work and everything else seems to be normal as well, just the group settings won't.

Do I need any subscriptions? Or is it just a bug?

Comment: Can you include as many screenshots as possible please?

Comment: After switching to your Azure AD B2C tenant and opening Azure AD B2C->Users and Groups->All groups, are there any groups listed?  If not, select "+ New Group" and create a group before editing a user.

Comment: If this helps anyone as a reference, here is listing of all Azure AD features and the plans you need in order to use them:  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/pricing/details/active-directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need any subscriptions? Or is it just a bug?

This is not about subscription and it's not about a bug.

**This content applies only to Office 365 groups(Unified groups)** .

Office 365 Groups settings are configured using a Settings object and a SettingsTemplate object. Initially, you don't see any Settings objects in your directory, because your directory is configured with the default settings.

To change the default settings, you must create a new settings object using a settings template. Settings templates are defined by Microsoft. There are several different settings templates.

To configure Office 365 group settings for your directory, you use the template named "Group.Unified". To configure Office 365 group settings on a single group, use the template named "Group.Unified.Guest". This template is used to manage guest access to an Office 365 group.

See more details about Azure Active Directory cmdlets for configuring group settings in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-accessmanagement-groups-settings-cmdlets).

---

**Update**

You can also use Azure AD Premium to enable this setting. Azure AD basic or free does not support Group settings. You can try to [get Azure Active Directory Premium free for one month](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/trial/get-started-active-directory/). Then you can enable Self-service group management to Yes:

[image]

Comment: Hi, @LHunold. If this answer is helpful to you ,pleas mark it as answer , so that we can help more people. Thanks!